# computing the intersection point of an ellipse and a line in Processing

Tags: java, processing, trigonometry

I'm having trouble computing the intersection point of an ellipse and a line.

Let's say I have an ellipse at point (0/0) with radius 500. Additionaly I'm drawing a line from point (0/0) to (`mouseX, mouseY`).

First I check if the mouse coordinates are outside the ellipse by doing

```
if((mouseX*mouseX)+(mouseY*mouseY)) > 500*500){/*...*/}
```

Now, whenever the mouse coordinates are outside that ellipse, I want to draw the line not until the mouse, but until the 'border' of the ellipse. In order to do so, I must have the intersection point of the line and the ellipse.

Are there any libraries that simplify such trigonometric tasks? Is there any other more or less easy way to compute the intersection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said, I'm making the following assumptions:

- The ellipse is always circular (same radius all the way round).
- The line is always being drawn from the centre of the circle.

If those are true then the problem is actually very simple. All you need to do is truncate the line so that its length is the same as the circle's radius, and that gives you the intersection point.

If the mouse is outside the ellipse:

1. Store the vector describing the line; in this case (mouseX, mouseY).
2. Normalize the vector (divide each component by the length of the line).
3. Multiply the vector by the radius of the circle.

The vector now contains the intersection point, relative to the centre of the circle.

You don't have to use a vector class for this, although it might help.

If your circle and line aren't starting on the origin (0,0) then you'll need to compensate. At step 1, subtract your new origin from (mouseX,mouseY). After step 3, add the origin back in to get the display coordinates.